# Docker/Dash-Create User If Not Exists

Tags: bash, docker

I'm creating a Docker container off of the `ubuntu:22.04` that creates a user if they don't already exists.  I have the following line which works in `bash`.

`RUN export MUNGEUSER=1001 && id -u munge &>/dev/null || useradd  -m -c "MUNGE Uid 'N' Gid Emporium" -d /var/lib/munge -u $MUNGEUSER -g munge  -s /sbin/nologin munge`

The line above works in `bash` but not in `dash` which I think is the default shell used by Docker.

I have two questions.

1. Is there a way for me to run the commands listed using `bash`, and keep the default `dash` shell
2. Should my `id -u munge &>/dev/null` piece re-written to be `dash` compliant?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to run the commands listed using bash, and keep the default dash shell

You can run bash but first you'd have to install it.  I wouldn't bother.

> Should my id -u munge &>/dev/null piece re-written to be dash compliant?

Dash implements Bourne, so just change the redirect to be bourne compatible (also works with bash).

```
id -u munge >/dev/null 2>&1
```